# Customizing TFS 2013 Build Process Template

Tags: build-process-template

I have added few arguments to the existing Build Process template, so I can pass those arguments to Powershell Script which was invoked as part of build customization. I had defined those values for arguments under build process tab but somehow those arguments value are not showing up  whenever build was queued.

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

1. In TFS 2013, the default build process template has included run script and add arguments, you can use it directly instead of customizing the build process template to invoke powershell scripts:

[image]

2. You need to add arguments in Process Parameter Metadata Editor, then you'll see these arguments on Process tab in build definition. Refer to this blog: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-2-Add-arguments-and-variables.aspx

[image]

3. Make sure you have checked in the custom build process template, and select the correct build process template in your build definition.

> 4. You can go to TFS web access to check **Diagnostics** log to see whether you can see the arguments you added. If you can see them on
>      Web Access, then your customization is correct. If you find you can
>      see the arguments on web access, but not in VS, try to change the
>      **BuildMessageImportance** of the variable to **High**.

[image]

Comment: The referenced site is dead and gone.
On a side note - Why do so many people leave questions on SO; only to never come back and follow up on any comments?